# Value picklist set - how to make them dependant picklists?

Tags: dependent-picklist, global-picklist

I have converted a picklist to Global Valueset picklist, but the 'Controlling' option is now missing from the field.

Is that by design?

Can fields that are based on Global Picklist (Value sets) not act as controlled/controlling fields?

Comment: This also happened to me. Have not found any documentation on it though. Field was also misbehaving afterward, showed not applicable. Found another post that mentioned that it can take a while for the change to be reflected in the org. I have not verified this personally.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019VeTQAU